# Find the Build version in semantic format for React App

Tags: shell, build.gradle, version, npm-scripts, react-scripts

I want to create the version number in semantic format and it should be done while doing the build for `npm build` and it should generate the json file containing version.js consuming the version number .After that i need to put the  version number into  inside the react web app header . I would like to know the best approach to do that ...

Answer (score 0):

```
!/bin/bash

# Copy a .env.${NODE_ENV} file (ex: .env.production) as a .env file in the root folder.
# if NODE_END is not set, will use 'development' as default

set -e # Exit with nonzero exit code if anything fails

ENV=dev
SOURCE_PREFIX="${PWD}/ops/.env."
TARGET="${PWD}/.env"

echo "== Start .env copy =="

# Setting ENV
if [ -z "${NODE_ENV}" ]
then
    echo "NODE_ENV environment variable is not set. Will default ENV to $ENV"
else
    ENV=${NODE_ENV}
    echo "ENV is set to NODE_ENV value '${NODE_ENV}'"
fi

ENV_FILE=$SOURCE_PREFIX$ENV


# Checking if env file exist
if [ ! -f $ENV_FILE ]; then
    echo "Expected config file '$ENV_FILE' not found. Stopping script."
    exit 1
fi

echo "Copying $ENV_FILE to $TARGET..."
cp $ENV_FILE $TARGET
```

### package.json

```
"start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev npm run env && react-scripts start",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=prod npm run env && react-scripts start",
    "env": "sh ops/env.sh",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

### external file

```
REACT_APP_ENV=dev
REACT_APP_COPYRIGHTTEXT=2018 @Famelike_Dev
REACT_APP_SOCKET_URL=http://localhost:8080
REACT_APP_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: Your shebang is wrong and you're missing a few double quotes - [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).